# Error Processes in Laravel for a Python file

Tags: python, php, laravel

what I want is to run a python file from Laravel, and for that I want to use process like this:

```
$result = Process::run('python readSitemaps.py');

return $result->errorOutput();
```

And it appears to me:

```
"python" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program, or executable batch file.
```

The problem is that no matter what I put in the process, I get the same error. If you will place the example from the Laravel documentation

```
$result = Process::run('ls -la');

return $result->output();
```

Comment: Use the full path to your `python` binary (and probably also for your script)

Comment: You can make the python file executable, add a shebang to the top of it (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`), and then just provide the ful path to your script.

Note: This apply if you are running on UNIX/Linux systems. For Windows, just provide the absolute path to both the interpreter and the script (see @brombeer's comment)

Comment: @brombeer How is it placed in code? Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install latest python version. if you are using windows then check for environment path variables also.

you can try by using

```
$file = escapeshellcmd(public_path('pathToYour/file.py'));
$result = shell_exec($file);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Why not use Laravel [Processes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/processes)?

Comment: its upon you, which method is easy and best fit for you, if you prefer to use Processes you can use it .